# Nougat not able to wifi debug

Tags: android, android-debug

Before upgrade to android nougat, I am able to debug app through WiFi:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.101:5555
```

But since upgrade to android version 7, it refuse to connect.

Comment: have you re-enabled wireless debugging after upgrade?

Comment: how to re-enable wireless debugging?

Comment: same way as you enabled it first time - in the developer settings

Comment: I just enable usb debugging, there is not wireless debugging.

Comment: ok, some devices have a setting item to enable wifi debug. If the device does not have such item, you will need to root it and install one of the apps found in google play by `adb wifi` search request.